# Can I confirm that: getting the object (a constructor returns) to invoke its constructor property is something the new operator achieves?

Tags: javascript

Not sure if it's a bit silly but I had a go at trying to create a constructor function that makes an instance of an object that *doesn't need to use `new`*.

`C()` is trying to emulate `new C()`.

What I got stuck on was getting the new object to immediately call its constructor method.

Can I confirm this is something that the `new` operator somehow achieves?

```js
C = function () {
    this.color = '';
    this.makeColor = function () {
      this.color = "yellow";
    }.bind(this)

    return {
        constructor: C
    }
}

i = C(); 
console.log(i);
```

Comment: I'm confused. What is this construct actually trying to emulate? `new C()`? Or something different? Can you show an equivalent normal code that uses `new` for what the target is?

Comment: Also, I don't know if it helps, but `new` doesn't really do that much magic. Calling `new F()` is mostly the same as `newObj = {}; Object.setPrototypeof(newObj, F); F.call(newObj)`. Well, that and there is *slight* shenanigans happening if `F` has or doesn't have a `return` value. Still, for most cases that would be a close enough representation.

Comment: @VLAZ yes `C()` is trying to emulate `new C()`

Comment: The way you call `C`, `this` will be the global object or undefined (in strict mode). If you use `this`, make sure it is bound to something you want.

Comment: Well if you expect `new C()` to actually call that `constructor: C` you return [it doesn't do it](https://jsbin.com/fuxujol/edit?js,console). It's part of the shenanigans that happen when the function you invoke with `new` - if the function returns a non-null object value, then you get *that* instead of a new instance.

Comment: If on the other hand that `constructor` property *would* have been called (automatically), then you would have an infinite recursion. I don't understand why you want to return such an object anyway.

Comment: @VLAZ Ah sorry I meant I'm trying to make a constructor function that does the work of `new` so you don't need `new`. For instance, I understand constructor function (with `new`) returns an empty object with a constructor property that is set to the constructor function. Will re-edit my question so I'm a bit more clear.

Comment: Assuming [this is your starting point](https://jsbin.com/mehogiwowi/1/edit?js,console) then [this is a simple re-implementation of what `new` does](https://jsbin.com/ninihituqo/1/edit?js,console). It covers most of what's happening. [This is a more complete implementation of what `new` does](https://jsbin.com/kenapageha/1/edit?js,console) the biggest difference is handling arguments and the return value. But the return value is *usually* the newly created object in the vast majority of cases - I added it for clarity, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `new` then your function can still construct an object. You don't need to return an object with a constructor property, but a (constructed) object.

One other difference you have to be aware of: `this` will *not* be set to the constructed object if you don't use `new`. `this` will be the global object (`window`) or `undefined` in strict mode. Instead use your own variable (you need to initialise it).

Here is an example:

```js
var C = function () {
    let that = {}; // <-- don't use `this`, but your own variable
    that.color = '';
    that.makeColor = function () {
        that.color = "yellow";
    }.bind(that);

    return that; // <--- just return the object
}

let obj = C(); 
console.log(obj);
```

NB: don't define variables without `var`, `let` or `const`. Also, `i` is a variable name that is most often used for a number (like a loop variable). It looks strange to see that variable name used for an object.